# Is there correct terminology for the two classes in a UML composition relationship?

Tags: uml, composition

[image: Composition]

Is there a correct way to refer to the two classes in this relationship? I was thinking of something similar to A being the parent and B being the child, but this sounds wrong for composition.

Answer (score 1):

A UML composition is intended to capture a special case of a part-whole relationship. Since it's called "composition", it seems natural to call the two classes involved ***component class*** and ***composite class***.

Comment: I was going to suggest "whole" and "part" but I think your answer is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no accepted standard for the names of these classes.

The UML standard text uses terms Container - Part. But they are not parts of the standard itself, they are merely terms used for explanation.

The most often and, IMHO, convenient terms are: A is container class, B is item class.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you actually pointed to the UML standard where these terms are used.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is only an example of use, not what we must use. If you want to know how they use the term, simply search the pdf for  "container". Many examples are there.